# python: override a single dict key based on a separate dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm sure a question like this exists somewhere on here but I can't seem to find it. I have the following dictionary called `query`:

```
query = {'day': 0, 'item': 'Chipotle'}
```

And a mapping dictionary:

```
day_mapping = {0:2, 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7, 6:1}
```

I need to override `query` to produce the following dictionary based on the mapping:

```
query = {'day': 2, 'item': 'Chipotle'}
```

Note `query` may or may not contain the key `day` so the following should return no error:

```
query = {'item': 'Chipotle'}
```

This is what I've come up with so far but there's gotta be a better way using list comprehension or something:

```
for k, v in query.items():
    if k == 'day':
        query[k] = day_mapping[v]
```

The reason for this is the numeric representation for days is different for python's `calendar` library and MongoDB's `aggregation` framework. Kinda annoying but I'm sure this happens all over the place.

Comment: why are you looping over query.items at all? You can just do a simple `if 'day' in query`

Comment: `if 'day' in query: query['day'] = day_mapping[query['day']]`

Comment: You can either use some of the approaches in the dupe, or go with the EAFP approach. It depends how exceptional you expect such a case to be. If it is truly exceptional, exceptions are the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `try` to replace it. This avoids one unnecessary hashing (compared to using `if 'day' in query:`) or looping over the dictionary and follows Pythons [EAFP principle](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
try:
    query['day'] = day_mapping[query['day']]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `dict.get(..)` to check for the presence of `'day'` key in your `dict` as:

```
query = {'day': 0, 'item': 'Chipotle'}
day_mapping = {0:2, 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7, 6:1}

day = query.get('day')  # returns `None` if 'day' key not found in `dict`
if day is not None:
    query['day'] = day_mapping[day]
```

Updated value of `query` dict in above example will be:

```
{'day': 2, 'item': 'Chipotle'}
```